# Tensorflow C API compiled as .so library __gnu_cxx::recursive_init_error

Tags: c, tensorflow, .so

Working with Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64, GCC 9.4.0, Tensorflow C API Linux CPU only.

A simple C++ tensorflow model prediction code with [cppflow](https://serizba.github.io/cppflow/index.html) wrap.

```
//this is predict.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "cppflow/cppflow.h"

int predict() {
    auto input = cppflow::decode_jpeg(cppflow::read_file(std::string("../my_cat.jpg")));
    input = cppflow::cast(input, TF_UINT8, TF_FLOAT);
    input = cppflow::expand_dims(input, 0);
    cppflow::model model("../model");
    auto output = model(input);
    std::cout << "It's a tiger cat: " << cppflow::arg_max(output, 1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    predict();
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with `g++` as executable file, it works fine.

```
g++ -o predict.out predict.cpp -ltensorflow
./predict.out
```

However, when I compile this code as a `.so` library.

```
//this is predict.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "cppflow/cppflow.h"

extern "C" int predict() {
    auto input = cppflow::decode_jpeg(cppflow::read_file(std::string("./my_cat.jpg")));
    input = cppflow::cast(input, TF_UINT8, TF_FLOAT);
    input = cppflow::expand_dims(input, 0);
    cppflow::model model("./model");
    printf("model created\n");
    auto output = model(input);
    printf("model predicted\n");
    std::cout << "It's a tiger cat: " << cppflow::arg_max(output, 1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with a g++ command
`g++ -fPIC -shared -o predict.so predict.cpp -ltensorflow`
load and execute from another `.cpp` file, for example:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int (*predict)();
int main()
{
    void* handle=dlopen("./predict.so",RTLD_LAZY);
    predict=(int(*)(void))dlsym(handle, "predict");
    dlclose(handle);

    predict();

    return 0;
}
```

I got is error.

```
model created
terminate called after throwing an instance of '__gnu_cxx::recursive_init_error'
terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively
```

since cppflow is just a wrap of [Tensorflow C AIP](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c), I looked into the `auto output = model(input);` line which caused this error. It turned out the execution of below sentence of TF C API triggered this error

```
  TF_SessionRun(this->session.get(), /*run_options*/ NULL,
                inp_ops.data(), inp_val.data(), static_cast<int>(inputs.size()),
                out_ops.data(), out_val.get(), static_cast<int>(outputs.size()),
                /*targets*/ NULL, /*ntargets*/ 0, /*run_metadata*/ NULL,
                this->status.get());
```

put it in another words, when a `.cpp` file containing `TF_SessionRun()` is compiled with g++ as `.out`, it works. Exported and compiled as`.so` library and executed in another `.cpp` file, it fails.
A more interesting thing is, when execute the function from `.so` library multiple times, the error message isn't always the same, sometimes, it prints

```
model created
terminate called after throwing an instance of '__gnu_cxx::recursive_init_error'
terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively
```

and some times

```
model created
terminate called recursively
terminate called after throwing an instance of '__gnu_cxx::recursive_init_error'
```

look like it is a random wrong memory access error. I checked the error information and the document says:

> 'If control re-enters the declaration (recursively) while the object is being initialized, the behavior is undefined.'

Still, I can't figure it out why the`.out` works while the `.so` failed, when both are compiled with one same compiler. Is it the way I exported the `.so` library caused this problem? Looking for some clues, appreciate.